# How to make a multiple select query in Firebird

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird, resultset

In MySQL I can perform the query I pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/PFRB2X0b). This query results the following result set:

[image: result set from the pastebin query]

How can I do something like it against a Firebird database?

Comment: Should work in Firebird as well. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `from RDB$DATABASE` to the end of your query - see [here](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq30/).

Comment: And of course removing the backtick quotes for the column aliases but either no quotes or quoted with a double-quote "